# passing parameter using jQuery Ajax call to asmx service

Tags: jquery

I am trying to pass a string to an asmx service. Actually, the parameter is a number with leading zeros, but the asmx gets the string with leading zeros removed.

How to avoid the truncation of leading zeros.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

pre-pend it with something that you the know to remove?